# DataGrid memory until user confirm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve. 
I have an application developed with ASP.NET MVC 4 - C #. The user makes a query from a table in the database. The result of this search must be displayed in a grid that the user should be able to add or remove records. This manipulation of data in the grid must be done in memory until the user completes and confirms the data which will be stored in the database. I tried using List, but when I work with more than one session, the data is replaced.

Do I have to use DataTable, DataSet?

Added:

I solved by adding the result of the query to a DataTable and then storing the DataTable in user session. Is this the only way to keep the data in memory?

Comment: Please explain this better.

Comment: Session - implies a web-app you are developing - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you mean by "I tried using List, but when I work with more than one session, the data is replaced". The data in the database is replaced?

I'd recommend using an ORM, such as Entity Framework or NHibernate, there are plenty quality OSS that will suite your needs.

NHibernate: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET

Entity Framework: http://entityframework.codeplex.com